# Some questions about number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

As a new beginner in algebraic number theory, I am confused with some properties of number fields.

First comes some conventional notations. For any number field $K$, let $\mathcal{O}_K$ denote the set of algebraic integers in $K$.

1. When $B = \mathcal{O}_K$ is given, is $K$ uniquely determined? If so, how can we determine the number field $K$? If not, can we find some counterexamples?
2. The previous question can be generalized in the following manner: given a set $B$ of algebraic integers, how to find a number field $K$ such that $\mathcal{O}_K = B$?
3. Given some fixed algebraic integers $\theta, \alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n$, if $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, can we say $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\theta]$? More generally, if $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n)$, can we say $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n]$?

Thanks!!

Comment: ($1$) The field $K$ is just the fraction field of $\mathcal O_K$. ($2$) There is no general answer, e.g., not with $B = {\mathbf Z}[2i]$. ($3$) It is not generally true if you write $K = \mathbf Q(\theta)$ for an algebraic integer $\theta$ that $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\theta]$. One example is $K = \mathbf Q(2i)$, but often $\mathcal O_K$ is not of the form $\mathbf Z[\theta]$ for *any* $\theta$ at all, e.g., $K = \mathbf Q(\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is a root of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 8$ (this example is due to Dedekind and is the first example found with such a property).

Answer (score 1):

This will to some extent repeat KCd's comment, but that's unavoidable.

1. $K$ is the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_K$.
2. A set is very little structure. First of all, $B$ should at the very least be a ring of algebraic integers. Then $B$ has an associated fraction field $K$, and there is a natural inclusion from $B$ into the ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ of algebraic integers of $K$ which is not always an isomorphism; as KCd indicates in the comments, $\mathbb{Z}[2i]$ is a counterexample. A useful keyword here is the property of being [integrally closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed).
3. No; as KCd mentions, $\mathbb{Z}[2i]$ is again a counterexample, but there are slightly less obvious ones like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, where the ring of integers in the fraction field is $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} \right]$, and much less obvious ones where it's not possible to express $\mathcal{O}_K$ in the form $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for any $\alpha$ (again as KCd mentions).

Comment: Thanks for your great examples!